# Using sed to extract data from a file. I know the string I'm looking but I need to get the whole block of data that this string is in

Tags: sed, scripting

I'm using sed to extract data from a file. Lots of same style data in there. I want every occurrence of a specific string occurs but the string is part of a block of information and I want to extract the whole block based of that string.

Example data in file:
123
AAA
ABC
ZZZ
123
KJG
HJY
ZZZ
123
LPC
ABC
TRY
ZZZ

In this example 123 is the start of the block of data I want and ZZZ the end. ABC is the string I search for. So from this example my output should be:

123
AAA
ABC
ZZZ
123
LPC
ABC
TRY
ZZZ

sed -n '/ABC/{:a;p;n;/123/b;ba};' testfile.txt > testfile2.txt

the output with this is
ABC
ZZZ
ABC
TRY
ZZZ

so I'm not getting the data before ABC in the block

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/123/{:a;N;/ZZZ/!ba;/ABC/p}' file
```

Gather up lines between `123` and `ZZZ` and then print them if they contain `ABC`.

N.B. `n` prints the current line and replaces it with the next. Whereas `N` appends the next line to the pattern space, inserting a newline. Thus keeping those lines current and searchable.